# Is it possible to automate `EXEC tSQLt.RunAll` in SQL Agent?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, tsqlt

I have followed the examples from [tSQLt](http://tsqlt.org/user-guide/tsqlt-tutorial/) and have successfully created unit and integration tests for my SQL Server database. I know that Redgate sells DevOps tools for automating tSQLt unit and integration tests, but I don't have that kind of money.

My no-cost idea was to run a SQL Agent task on a schedule. It's easy enough to create a T-SQL Job Step with the command `EXEC tSQLt.RunAll;`. While I have SQL Agent configured to send me emails if a job step fails, I don't know how Agent would know whether I had any failing tests when running the `EXEC tSQLt.RunAll;` step and alert me.

There's nothing to stop me from manually running these tests, but I really would love to automate them so I can focus on other things.

Has anyone been able to do this or achieve a similar result using SQL Agent?

Comment: If the tests fail that will raise an error so the job will error and you can use normal SQL Agent error alerting. But how do you deploy changes ? Can you integrate it into that?

Comment: @MartinSmith -- SQL Agent works as you described. In my case it's to act as an early warning system for when users supply incorrect data. It prompts me to create more unit tests and diversion-to-error-table scripts.

Comment: You are not using tSQLt in production, @RandomHandle, are you? Your "when users supply incorrect data" is worrying me a little.
tSQLt is good at isolating the object under test from the rest of the database. But that also means that tSQLt does stuff under the covers that could "cause pain" within a production system.

Comment: It's not a traditional production system. It's an intranet website used by a few non-techy people. It's also a database that is never done because the users want to keep evolving it. I know I'm breaking one of the rules, but I've got to do something. Maybe "integration test" isn't the right term: I'm testing for real data records during scheduled refreshes that would cause one or more "tests" to fail and flag me to adjust the system. (Training the users is not always an option.)

Comment: So "development" happens untested on this server? If so, and you don't mind the risk of things going wrong, then using an agent job will suffice. But it feels like this is a little too late to find problems.

Comment: @DavidAtkinson -- It has been "debug-oriented development". Not pretty, but it's only lately that I've heard about tsqlt and fitting testing into the picture late is better than never.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Martin Smith points out, tSQLt raises an error at the end of the execution if any of the tests failed or ran into an exception. Any errors throughout are caught, so you will always get a complete run.

The Agent allows you to capture the output, so you will be able to see what failed.